# When adding a hyperlink - setting url to a string- string becomes urlencoded

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink, addition, urlencode

I am adding a hyperlink with the following code:

```
Dim HyperlinksAdd as String

HyperlinksAdd = "[MyWorkBook.xlsm]thissheet!C1"

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("linksheet").Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("linksheet").Cells(3, 3), _ Address:=HyperlinksAdd, _
TextToDisplay:="Link to thissheet cell c1"
```

When I run the code the hyperlink is created however the address is urlencoded as follow --obtained from when I right click on the link and select properties.

Address is  %5bMyWorkBook.xlsm%5dthissheet!C1

notice the [ is changed to %5b and ] is changed to %5d

any ideas on why this is happening?

Thanks

Comment: Why it's happening? Because hyperlinks cannot have certain characters in them, so they need to be URL encoded.

Comment: Reserved URI characters, see [Percent-encoding from Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)